# Formulating a linear mixed model with multiple random effects when one is not independent

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design, nested-data

I have a randomized complete block design. I have formulated linear mixed models using R, the package lme4, and the function lmer for all measurements except for one, where I am stuck on the random effects.

The design: 96 pLots (`plot`) with 48 tilled and 48 with no-till (`tillage`). In each half, there are 6 plant species (`species`) with 2 different fertilizers  (`fert`) and each combination is replicated 4 times(`repl`).

The measurements in question are nitrate measurements, that were taken on two different dates (`date`) in three different depths (`depth`).
I have one model to look at the overall differences in nitrate regardless of depth:

```
~ species*fert*tillage*depth + (1|date:repl)
```

But I would also like one with information about each depth. I know that if I add depth as a random factor I have to add plot as well since the depths are not independent measurements. I have tried this:

```
~ species*fert*tillage*depth + (1|date:repl:plot:depth)
```

but this results in the error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations. So how can I nest depth in plot in this case?

Comment: I don't really understand your question and that's probably because you are working under wrong assumptions: Your first model doesn't "look at the overall differences [...] regardless of depth" because you include depth as a fixed effect. In your second model, it appears the grouping factors `date:repl:plot:depth` are sufficient to identify each distinct observation, which explains the error.